# Deleting SSL certificate from Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, ssl

I want to permanently delete SSL certificate from Windows Server 2008. What I did is open up the mmc window and selected the certificate from the machine store and click delete. This removed the certificate from the certificate store. I just want to know if this action deleted the certificate completely from the machine and want to make sure that its private key is also deleted. The action I did is correct or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the key will be deleted with the certificate. You would need to export them first if you want to be able to restore them at some point.

Comment: When I import certificate, a file is created under C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys.   But when I delete certificate it does not delete file from that location.

Comment: I mean is it safe to leave the files in C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys once I delete certificate from mmc.

Comment: That file is a container for keys. The actual key will be removed from the container when the key is deleted.